# how to pass multiple values to query using jdbcTemplate in spring

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

In my Spring Hibernate application i have all the sql queries in one common_queries.xml file,where some queries require 2 to 3 parameters shown as below

```
   <query id="mining.fuel" no-of-params="2">
select ms.id id,ms.name value,concat(ms.name,' ','  (',ms.code,')') label,ms.rate rate     from mining_fuel ms where ms.name like '?' and ms.fuel_type_id=?  LIMIT 10
 </query>
```

In my daoImpl i get this query

```
lookupList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(q1.getQuery());
```

I will get the query here,but how to pass the value of '?'s here, i have those 2 values with me in daoImpl.. pl send the code of how to achieve this.I dont want to use prepared statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [this overload](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) which takes an Object vararg for passing the query parameters:

```
lookupList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(q1.getQuery(), value1, value2, value3);
```

Comment: well, i tried that i have 2 values like (q1.getQuery(),lookupValue,filterType);but when i hardcode lookupValue and pass only one parameter filterType its working fine, but when i do it reverse its throwing                                               java.sql.SQLException: No parameters defined during prepareCall()  and when i pass both values its throwing                           java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of bounds. 2 is not between valid values of 1 and 1                                     .Is there any problem with the select query near 'like' i have mentioned above?

Comment: Try to remove the quotes around the first `?`: `like ?`.

Comment: actually i want to use ( like ' ?% ' ) but if i remove single quotes     ( like ?% ) its showing sql grammer exception..If i use with quotes its showin parameter out of bounds exception.

Comment: I guess you need to use it without quotes and have the '%' appended to the value: `... like ? ...`, and then your value should be `someString + '%'`

Answer (score 4):

I think that you only need to create an Object array with the params used by the query, take in mind that the order is important because value1 will be the first replacement for ? in the query.

```
lookupList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(q1.getQuery(), new Object[]{value1, value2, value3});
```

Answer (score 0):

First calls the queryForList method on jdbctemplate reference and pass query and object type array in this object type array we must pass only objects means if we have id it is int type we have to convert to object type while putting inside object array.

lookupList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(q1.getQuery, new Object[]{designation, new Integer(id), new Float(sal)}