# Spring jdbcTemplate null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to use jdbcTemplate to execute sql commands. In this case, I'm trying to insert things into a table. I'm getting a null pointer exception in the line : `jdbcTemplate.execute(subscriptionStatusInsertQuery);`

When I try to run the line:
`dbMapper.mapToDatabase(newEntry);`
where dbMapper is an instance of DBMapper.

```
@Repository
public class DBMapper {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void mapToDatabase(Status status) {
        String id = status.getId();

        String subscriptionStatusInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO t1 (ID) VALUES (id)";
        jdbcTemplate.execute(subscriptionStatusInsertQuery);
    }
}
```

I've tried not having a setter for jdbcTemplate. I've tried taking out the @Repository annotation. I've tried having a setter that included datasource. Still getting error.

How should I fix this null pointer exception?

Edit:

My application.properties has the following setting:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ee_internal
spring.datasource.username=ee
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

And from my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Personally I think it would be more readable to have the `Autowire` annotation on the field instead the setter. My guess is that `DBMapper` is not picked up as a bean. Please provide your spring configuration.

Comment: You forgot to pass the id parameter into the query ==>  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009709/how-to-pass-multiple-values-to-query-using-jdbctemplate-in-spring

Comment: Try this code snippet:
 

            `String subscriptionStatusInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO t1 (ID) VALUES ( ? )";
            int updatedRows = jdbcTemplate.update(subscriptionStatusInsertQuery, new Object[]{id});`

Comment: @hotzst, I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Grayson tried that and still getting same error

Comment: I added my spring application.properties

Comment: @AlanGuo Are you still getting a null pointer? How are your datasource and jdbctemplate configured?

Comment: @Grayson Yes I'm still getting a null pointer. I added the xml dependency in my pom.xml in the original post.